# Como criar nomes de arquivos aleatórios com o ffmpeg?

Tags: c, algoritmo, random

Estou compilando uma versão customizada do ffmpeg, e quero que ele gere nomes de aquivos aleatorios mas ele não oferece suporte a isso, então preciso de alguma função que faça isso com **X** caracteres(*a quantidade não é importande, desde que fique a cima de* 10 *e abaixo de* 20), se possível, gostaria de saber como fazer isso apenas com números e com caracteres alfanuméricos.

O objetivo disso, é incorporar a geração de nomes de arquivos aleatórios, integrando essa função a já existente, `hls->use_localtime`/`pattern_localtime_fmt` que representa a geração de nomes com base no datetime.

Usando `%%Y-%%m-%%dT%%H.%%M.%%S.%%I.ts` com `-use_localtime 1` é possível obter o seguinte resultado `2016-10-30T15.12.32.03.ts`.

Sabendo disso, como eu poderia gerar um resultado aleatório como por exemplo 
`2016-10-30T15.12.32.03-41u7aai73y.ts` ou `016-10-30T15.12.32.03-07931993501.ts`?

Seria possível alterar código abaixo para implementar as modificações propostas acima?

O código hlsenc.c:

```
static int hls_write_header(AVFormatContext *s)
{
    HLSContext *hls = s->priv_data;
    int ret, i;
    char *p;
    const char *pattern = "%d.ts";
    const char *pattern_localtime_fmt = "-%s.ts";
    AVDictionary *options = NULL;
    int basename_size;

    hls->sequence       = hls->start_sequence;
    hls->recording_time = hls->time * AV_TIME_BASE;
    hls->start_pts      = AV_NOPTS_VALUE;

    if (hls->format_options_str) {
        ret = av_dict_parse_string(&hls->format_options, hls->format_options_str, "=", ":", 0);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(s, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Could not parse format options list '%s'\n", hls->format_options_str);
            goto fail;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < s->nb_streams; i++) {
        hls->has_video +=
            s->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
    }

    if (hls->has_video > 1)
        av_log(s, AV_LOG_WARNING,
               "More than a single video stream present, "
               "expect issues decoding it.\n");

    hls->oformat = av_guess_format("mpegts", NULL, NULL);

    if (!hls->oformat) {
        ret = AVERROR_MUXER_NOT_FOUND;
        goto fail;
    }

    if (hls->segment_filename) {
        hls->basename = av_strdup(hls->segment_filename);
        if (!hls->basename) {
            ret = AVERROR(ENOMEM);
            goto fail;
        }
    } else {
        if (hls->flags & HLS_SINGLE_FILE)
            pattern = ".ts";

        if (hls->use_localtime) {
            basename_size = strlen(s->filename) + strlen(pattern_localtime_fmt) + 1;
        } else {
            basename_size = strlen(s->filename) + strlen(pattern) + 1;
        }
        hls->basename = av_malloc(basename_size);
        if (!hls->basename) {
            ret = AVERROR(ENOMEM);
            goto fail;
        }

        av_strlcpy(hls->basename, s->filename, basename_size);

        p = strrchr(hls->basename, '.');
        if (p)
            *p = '\0';
        if (hls->use_localtime) {
            av_strlcat(hls->basename, pattern_localtime_fmt, basename_size);
        } else {
            av_strlcat(hls->basename, pattern, basename_size);
        }
    }

    if ((ret = hls_mux_init(s)) < 0)
        goto fail;

    if ((ret = hls_start(s)) < 0)
        goto fail;

    av_dict_copy(&options, hls->format_options, 0);
    ret = avformat_write_header(hls->avf, &options);
    if (av_dict_count(options)) {
        av_log(s, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Some of provided format options in '%s' are not recognized\n", hls->format_options_str);
        ret = AVERROR(EINVAL);
        goto fail;
    }
    av_assert0(s->nb_streams == hls->avf->nb_streams);
    for (i = 0; i < s->nb_streams; i++) {
        AVStream *inner_st  = hls->avf->streams[i];
        AVStream *outer_st = s->streams[i];
        avpriv_set_pts_info(outer_st, inner_st->pts_wrap_bits, inner_st->time_base.num, inner_st->time_base.den);
    }
fail:

    av_dict_free(&options);
    if (ret < 0) {
        av_freep(&hls->basename);
        if (hls->avf)
            avformat_free_context(hls->avf);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

*Este é apenas um trecho do hlsenc.c*.

Comment: Você pode usar a função `tmpnam()` para gerar nomes de arquivo aleatórios e depois concatenar com a data/hora que já tem disponível. Para maiores informações acesse: >[http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/tmpnam/](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/tmpnam/) Ou digite no terminal do teu linux:
>`man 3 tmpnam`

Comment: Relacionado [Problema após a aplicação de um patch para geração de nomes aleatorios no ffmpeg](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/166819/8984)