# Problema após a aplicação de um patch para geração de nomes aleatorios no ffmpeg

Tags: c, random, patch

Apliquei o seguinte patch abaixo, ele funciona como esperado, mas ocasionalmente a transcodificação para e em outros casos(*casos raros, dependendo da versão do ffmpeg compilada*) continua executando mas em vez de criar vários segmentos com nomes aleatórios, ele fica armazenando todos em um único arquivo de segmento.

Ou seja, olhando para o patch, existe alguma inconsistência nele? Se sim, como eu poderia resolver?

```
diff --git a/libavformat/utils.c b/libavformat/utils.c
index 17ae300..7ff8c22 100644
--- a/libavformat/utils.c
+++ b/libavformat/utils.c
@@ -3809,6 +3809,36 @@ uint64_t ff_ntp_time(void)
     return (av_gettime() / 1000) * 1000 + NTP_OFFSET_US;
 }

+static char *randstring(size_t length) {
+
+    static char charset[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
+    char *randomString;
+
+    if (length) {
+        randomString = malloc(sizeof(char) * (length +1));
+
+        if (randomString) {
+            for (int n = 0;n < length;n++) {
+                int key = rand() % (int)(sizeof(charset) -1);
+                randomString[n] = charset[key];
+            }
+
+            randomString[length] = '\0';
+        }
+    }
+
+    return randomString;
+}
+
+/**
+ * Random filename usage
+ *
+ * use "%<size>r" at -segment_format. <size> is the length of random string generated, for example: "%20r"
+ *
+ * command example:
+ * ffmpeg -i $1 -r 25 -c:a libfaac -ab:a 128k -ac:a 2 -c:v mpeg2video -s:v 640x360 -aspect:v 16:9 -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 120 -segment_list $2.m3u8 -segment_format mpegts "$2-%20r.ts"
+ */
+
 int av_get_frame_filename(char *buf, int buf_size, const char *path, int number)
 {
     const char *p;
@@ -3829,7 +3859,6 @@ int av_get_frame_filename(char *buf, int buf_size, const char *path, int number)
                     nd = nd * 10 + *p++ - '0';
                 c = *p++;
             } while (av_isdigit(c));
-
             switch (c) {
             case '%':
                 goto addchar;
@@ -3846,6 +3875,17 @@ int av_get_frame_filename(char *buf, int buf_size, const char *path, int number)
                 memcpy(q, buf1, len);
                 q += len;
                 break;
+            case 'r':
+                percentd_found = 1;
+                if (number < 0)
+                    nd += 1;
+                snprintf(buf1, sizeof(buf1), "%s", randstring(nd));
+                len = strlen(buf1);
+                if ((q - buf + len) > buf_size - 1)
+                    goto fail;
+                memcpy(q, buf1, len);
+                q += len;
+                goto addchar;
             default:
                 goto fail;
             }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se isso responde a pergunta, mas ficou grande demais para um comentário.

De cara, noto que `randstring(0)` retorna um ponteiro não-inicializado, o que é perigoso. Acho, mas não tenho certeza, que isso poderia ocorrer se `path` conter um `%0r`.

Entretanto, há um problema sério de *memory leak* em `randstring`. Essa função aloca memória no heap, devolve um ponteiro para `av_get_frame_filename` e a função `av_get_frame_filename` não chama `free` em lugar nenhum.

Assim, sugiro que a função `randstring` seja a seguinte:

```
static char *randstring(char *target, size_t length) {

    static char charset[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

    for (int n = 0; n < length - 1; n++) {
        int key = rand() % (int)(sizeof(charset) - 1);
        target[n] = charset[key];
    }

    if (length) target[length - 1] = '\0';

    return target;
}
```

Observe que `length` agora é o número de caracteres a serem escritos incluindo o `\0`, e não mais excluindo o `\0`. E também não precisamos mais usar `malloc` nesta função.

E então, na sua função `av_get_frame_filename` ao invés disso:

```
snprintf(buf1, sizeof(buf1), "%s", randstring(nd));
len = strlen(buf1);
```

Você põe isso:

```
len = sizeof(buf1);
if (len > nd + 1) len = nd + 1;
randstring(buf1, len);
```

Quanto ao resto da função `av_get_frame_filename`, não sei, pois não a entendi por completo ainda, embora tenha entendido mais ou menos o que ela faz.

Comment: Agradeço a explicação detalhada, também notei que o `free` não era chamado, mas ignorei isso diante de todo o cenário. Fiz as modificações, estou compilando para testar, também deixo aqui um link do CodeReview[(Random String generator in C)](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/29198) a respeito de uma função que ao que parece é a mesma dessa, logo vi, que ela tinha alguns problemas.